# How to magically get Object key?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

It is possible to get **hero** key in the translate function?

```js
let books = {
  hero: translate([
    'Batman',
    'Superman',
    'Ironman'
  ])
}

function translate(param1) {
  return ...
}
```

Maybe there is some magic how to get calling key name ? :) Thanks!

Comment: declare your book correctly

Comment: T.J. Crowder, yes, sorry, my bad ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking if a function called as part of a property initializer in an object initializer can access the name of the property its return value will be used to initialize.

No, it can't. Functions have no knowledge of how their return value will be used.